# How to create a list dynamically from a class name (which is passed as argument) and return the list in c#.net

Tags: list, dynamic

How to create a list dynamically from a class name (which is passed as an argument) and return the list in  C#.

Below code may not work. I have posted it to give an idea:

```
 public T ConvertDataSetToList<T>(DataSet _ds, String tableName, string className)
    {
        Type classType=Type.GetType(className);
        List<T> newList = new List<T>();

        //System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(className));

        try
        {
            Details _Details;
            for (int iRowCount = 0; iRowCount < _ds.Tables[tableName].Rows.Count; iRowCount++)
            {
                _Details = FillDTO(_ds.Tables[tableName].Rows[iRowCount]);
                newList.Add(_msDetails);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        return newList;
    }
```

Comment: what i want to do basically is to convert a dataset to list and return the list with the dataset, classname and tablename as arguments. please provide any other feasible solution if the above idea is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dot it with some basic mapping stuff.

```
//Maps a dataset
public List<T> MapDataSet<T>(DataSet anyDataset
                           , string tablename) where T : new()
{
  return MapDataTable<T>(anyDataset.Tables[tablename]);
}

// Maps a datatable
public List<T> MapDataTable<T>(DataTable table) where T : new()
{
  List<T> result = new List<T>();
  foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
  {
     result.Add(MapDataRow<T>(row));
  }
  return result;
}

// maps a DataRow to an arbitrary class (rudimentary)
public T MapDataRow<T>(DataRow row) where T: new()
{
  // we map columns to class properties
  Type destinationType = typeof(T);
  // create our new class
  T mappedTo = new T();
  // iterate over the columns
  for(int columnIndex=0;columnIndex<row.ItemArray.Length;columnIndex++)
  {
    // get a matching property of our class
    PropertyInfo fieldTo = destinationType.GetProperty(
                              row.Table.Columns[columnIndex].ColumnName );
    if (fieldTo !=null)
    {
       // map our fieldvalue to our property
       fieldTo.SetValue(mappedTo, row[columnIndex], new object[] {});
    }
    else
    {
     // sorry, field doens't match any property on class
    }
  }
  return mappedTo;
}
```

Here is basic test app to demonstrate its usage

```
void Main()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("hello");
    dt.Columns.Add("foo");
    dt.Columns.Add("bar");
    dt.Columns.Add("foobar");

    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0]="blah1";
    row[1] ="two";
     row[2] = "fb1";

    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    row = dt.NewRow();
    row[0]="apples";
    row[1] ="pears";
    row[2] = "duh";

    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    List<DTO> list = MapDataTable<DTO>(dt);
    List<SecondDTO> list2 = MapDataTable<SecondDTO>(dt);

}

// sample DTO object
public class DTO
{
  public string foo { get; set;}
  public string bar { get; set; }
}

// another sample DTO object
public class SecondDTO
{
  public string foo { get; set;}
  public string foobar { get; set; }
}
```